# how to prevent div from getting larger

Tags: html, static, size

Is there way to stop parent div to change its size when some other contents are appended in it.

```
<div style="width:220px;height:245" >''      
 <img src="images/pano_doc.png" style="width:220px;height:245"/>"

 <div style="position:relative;width:119px;height:173px;background-color:#0F3">     
 </div>      
</div>
```

After the second div created parent div's height becomes 245+173 but i need to fix its size so whatever is added in it, its size wouldn't change.

Comment: Unless you're using something like IE6 the parent `div` shouldn't get any larger than what you've specified with you `width` and `height` properties.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check http://jsbin.com/anides/1/edit

Try this, the only change made are

- width-max:220px; &
- overflow:auto;

Code

```
<div style="width-max:220px;height:245;overflow:auto;" >      
<img src="images/pano_doc.png" style="width:220px;height:245"/>

<div style="position:relative;width:119px;height:173px;background-color:#0F3">     
</div>      
</div>
```

Comment: for height work partiually. but width get larger now.in picture on the left side is what i get, right one what i need http://s7.postimage.org/kcbs922kb/Untitled.jpg

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: auto` will give the div scroll bars when needed.

`overflow: hidden` will clip the content when needed.

`overflow: visible` is the standard setting, and won't restrict the div's size.

[Reference at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow)